# Get total number of views for my contribution

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there a query in data explorer to calculate total number of views on all of my questions and those questions in which I participated by answering ?

What I like to do is:

1. Get all posts with my contribution (questions or answers)
2. Get the sum of views each post has.

I would like to calculate views shown on the right side of the post
[image]

and calculate sum of all views on post containing my contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely misunderstood the original post. My apologies. I whipped up a quick (and REALLY crude) data explorer query for you. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/187290/get-viewcount-on-posts-user-contributed-to?UserId=2711965. That will give you the view count of each post you contributed to.

---

According to [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), the view count is limited to the number of views on the post or profile. There's no additional data that's given out that would relate the views to a user.

I doubt that information would ever become public via the data explorer since you could start figuring out a users visiting habits. But you maybe able to create a feature request that could bring your personal view data to a location which you would be able to view? But to be honest, I'm not sure that data actually exists or not. There's a little discussion on [Dissecting the Stack Overflow views counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter)

Comment: Thank for the reply, I believe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I am not talking about views from a particular user, I want to get All the post where I have contributed, and their total number of views

Comment: @NewHire Updated my answer with a data explorer query

Comment: Thanks Steven, this is what I was looking for.